# VBs script to open .mdb file and update query

Tags: sql, vbscript

I do not have experience with VBs. I will need to connect and open .mdb file with protected password e.g. Password1 and user Admin.

I will need then to update the database inside with SQL statement:

```
update paytype set n_type = 0 where n_type = 1
```

Comment: You should be explaining what you have tried already, and ask help about where you are exactly stuck.

Comment: i do not have any experience wit vbs and do not know from where to start